# Java - AND operator not working

Tags: java

newbie here,
I have two variables which generate random numbers through `.Random`. I want them keep rolling until both variables generate two different values, simultaneously. Therefore, I'm using `while` loop with `&&` for this purpose. As I have understood, please correct me if I'm wrong, the line `while ((diceRolled1 != 5) && (diceRolled2 != 4))` translates as, keep rolling until the values of `diceRolled1` *is not equal to 5* **AND** `diceRolled2`*is not equal to 4*. But the program ends if either variable matches its value (diceRolled1 = 5 **OR** diceRolled2 = 4). This is not what `&&` is supposed to do, right? I have ran the code like 10s of times, but not a single time it generated 5 and 4 at the same time.

I also tried `==`on both sides and either side, but in that case the program didn't run at all, nor it gave any error.

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class DiceRoller {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random dice1 = new Random();
    Random dice2 = new Random();        //Removing this doesn't work either

    int diceRolled1 = 0;
    int diceRolled2 = 0;

    while ((diceRolled1 != 5) && (diceRolled2 != 4)) { //& didn't work either 
        diceRolled1 = dice1.nextInt(6) + 1;
        diceRolled2 = dice2.nextInt(6) + 1;
        out.println(diceRolled1 + " " + diceRolled2);
    }
    out.println("Program ends");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the logical result you describe, but it wasn't what you expect. Specifically, when either of your conditions evaluates to `false` the logical and will not evaluate to `true`. I think you wanted

```
while (!(diceRolled1 == 5 && diceRolled2 == 4)) {
```

which is `while` **not** dice1 equal to 5 **and** dice2 equal to 4. And then, using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) that might also be expressed as

```
while (diceRolled1 != 5 || diceRolled2 != 4) {
```

which means *loop* `while` dice1 is not equal to 5 **or** dice2 is not equal to 4.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is incorrect. The loop will continue as long as both values don't match - as soon as one value matches, the loop exits. We can invert your logic to show this:

```
while (!(diceRolled1 == 5 || diceRolled2 == 4)) {
```

which is logically equivalent to what you have.

What you want is this:

```
while (diceRolled1 != 5 || diceRolled2 != 4) {
```

which says "Continue while any variable does not have the desired value"

Comment: Sorry, your logic is also not working either (copied and pasted your code). It is behaving as the same as mine did.

Comment: It didn't here. I tried many times. But thank you so much for trying. Really appreciate it

Comment: @jalbal It was exactly the same as the answer you selected, so how did this not work but the other one did?

Comment: Ok, sorry it was my mistake. I was coping the above code. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

the while execute the statement untill the condition is true.
In your code the condition is given by (diceRolled1 != 5) && (diceRolled2 != 4).
The && operator require true that all operands be true. 
Given this Your loop will end when at least one of the expression will be false.

To finish the program when it generate 5 and 4 you have to use this:

(!(diceRolled1 == 5) && (diceRolled2 == 4))

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,it should be. The program should end if dicerolled is either 5 or 4 because as far as it is not 4 and not 5 it is in while loop. It exits the while loop if only the value is either 4 or 5. So your logic is incorrect. Sorry! :)
Try:

```
while (!(dicerolled ==4 && dicerolled == 5))
```